# shellscript to execute script in multiple database

Tags: shell

I've drafted a code to connected to multiple schema however only one schema it is execucting not connecting to sqlplus for other schema. Please help

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting file execution"
date
HOSTLIST="SCHEMA1 SCHEMA2"
for HOST in $HOSTLIST
do
 sqlplus $HOST/$HOST@hostname:1521/sid << EOF >> /output/folder/output.log
@insert.sql;
commit;
EOF
echo "Completed execution"
date
done
```

Comment: Try debugging with `bash -xv yourScript`

Comment: would gladly help! do you get any error?

Answer (score 0):

This script looks right.

You must check that alone, set the loop aside:

```
sqlplus SCHEMA2/SCHEMA2@hostname:1521/sid << EOF >> /output/folder/output.log
@insert.sql;
commit;
EOF
```

possibly SCHEMA2 cannot connect, or don't have sufficient right.

Also, you should have one output per execution:

```
 [..]
    sqlplus ${HOST}/${HOST}@hostname:1521/sid << EOF >> /output/folder/output_${HOST}.log
 [..]
```